# TCP connection returns 'broken pipe' error when used multiple times

Tags: go, networking, tcp, rpc

This question relates to go and its net package.

I wrote a simple tcp server handles some RPC. the client is using a `chan net.Conn` to manage all tcp connection on the client side. Server is running with a tcp listener.

here's the code:
client:

```
package server

import (
    "errors"
    "log"
    "net"
)

var tcpPool chan net.Conn

func NewClient(connections int, address string) {

    tcpPool = make(chan net.Conn, connections)
    for i := 0; i < connections; i++ {
        conn, err := net.Dial("tcp4", address)
        if err != nil {
            log.Panic(err)
        }
        tcpPool <- conn
    }
}

func SendMessage(msg []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    conn := getConn()

    log.Println("check conn: ", conn)
    log.Println("msg: ", msg)

    defer releaseConn(conn)
    // send message
    n, err := conn.Write(msg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    } else if n < len(msg) {
        log.Panic(errors.New("Message did not send in full"))
    }

    // receiving a message
    inBytes := make([]byte, 0)

    for {
        // bufsize 1024, read bufsize bytes each time
        b := make([]byte, bufSize)
        res, err := conn.Read(b)
        log.Println("server sends >>>>>>>>>>>>: ", res)
        if err != nil {
            b[0] = ReError
            break
        }
        inBytes = append(inBytes, b[:res]...)
        // message finished.
        if res < bufSize {
            break
        }
    }
    // check replied message
    if len(inBytes) == 0 {
        return []byte{}, errors.New("empty buffer error")
    }
    log.Println("SendMessage gets: ", inBytes)
    return inBytes, nil
}

func releaseConn(conn net.Conn) error {
    log.Println("return conn to pool")
    select {
    case tcpPool <- conn:
        return nil
    }
}

func getConn() (conn net.Conn) {
    log.Println("Take one from pool")
    select {
    case conn := <-tcpPool:
        return conn
    }
}
```

server

```
func StartTCPServer(network, addr string) error {
    listener, err := net.Listen(network, addr)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrapf(err, "Unable to listen on address %s\n", addr)
    }
    log.Println("Listen on", listener.Addr().String())
    defer listener.Close()
    for {
        log.Println("Accept a connection request.")
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Failed accepting a connection request:", err)
            continue
        }
        log.Println("Handle incoming messages.")
        go onConn(conn)
    }
}

//onConn recieves a tcp connection and waiting for incoming messages
func onConn(conn net.Conn) {
    inBytes := make([]byte, 0)
    defer func() {
        if e := recover(); e != nil {
            //later log
            if err, ok := e.(error); ok {
                println("recover", err.Error())
            }
        }
        conn.Close()
    }()
    // load msg
    for {
        buf := make([]byte, bufSize)
        res, err := conn.Read(buf)
        log.Println("server reading: ", res)
        inBytes = append(inBytes, buf[:res]...)
        if err != nil || res < bufSize {
            break
        }
    }

    var req RPCRequest
    err := json.Unmarshal(inBytes, &req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    log.Println("rpc request: ", req)

    var query UserRequest
    err = json.Unmarshal(req.Query, &query)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    log.Println("rpc request query: ", query)

    // call method to process request
    // good now we can proceed to function call
    // some actual function calls gets a output
    // outBytes, err := json.Marshal(out)
    conn.Write(outBytes)
}
```

I think this is very standard. but for some reason, I can only send message on the client side one, and then the follow 2nd and 3rd start to show some irregularity.

1st ---> success, gets response
2nd ---> client can send but nothing gets back, logs on server side shows no in coming message
3rd ---> if I send from client side one more time, it shows `broken pipe` error..

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but an important point on your terminology: Go doesn't have exceptions, and never throws them, or anything else. What you're talking about is _returning an error_, which is a fundamentally different behavior than what your title originally described. Understanding this difference is important when coding.

Comment: Aside: there is no need to check the error and int returned by Write separately: "Write must return a non-nil error if it returns n < len(p)." https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some bad handling way.
First, the flag to insure the msg from server finished is depending on io.EOF,not length

```golang
    // message finished.
    if res < 512 {
        break
    }
```

instead of this, reader returns an `io.EOF` is the only symbol that shows message finished.
Second, `chan type` has its property to block and not need to use select.by the way, you really need to start a goroutine to release. The same requirement for getConn

```golang
func releaseConn(conn net.Conn)  {
    go func(){
        tcpPool <- conn
    }()
}

func getConn() net.Conn {
    con := <-tcpPool
    return con
}
```

Third, listener should not be close, code below is bad

```
defer listener.Close()
```

The most important reason is
on the client side, 
`res, err := conn.Read(b)`  this receive the reply from the server.
when nothing reply ,it block rather than  io.EOF, nor some error else.
It means ,you cann't box a lasting communicating part into a function send().
You can do a single thing to use sendmsg() to send, but never use sendmsg() to handle the reply.
you can handle reply like this

```golang
var receive chan string

func init() {
    receive = make(chan string, 10)
}
func ReceiveMessage(con net.Conn) {
    // receiving a message
    inBytes := make([]byte, 0, 1000)
    var b = make([]byte, 512)
    for {
        // bufsize 1024, read bufsize bytes each time
        res, err := con.Read(b)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
            break
        }
        inBytes = append(inBytes, b[:res]...)
        msg := string(inBytes)
        fmt.Println("receive msg from server:" + msg)
        receive <- msg
    }
}
```

I found several problem in your code, but I can't tell which one leads your failure.
This is my code according to what you write and did some fixing.
client.go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
)

var tcpPool chan net.Conn
var receive chan string

func init() {
    receive = make(chan string, 10)
}
func NewClient(connections int, address string) {
    tcpPool = make(chan net.Conn, connections)
    for i := 0; i < connections; i++ {
        conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", address)
        if err != nil {
            log.Panic(err)
        }
        tcpPool <- conn
    }
}

func SendMessage(con net.Conn, msg []byte) error {
    // send message
    _, err := con.Write(msg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    return nil
}

func ReceiveMessage(con net.Conn) {
    // receiving a message
    inBytes := make([]byte, 0, 1000)
    var b = make([]byte, 512)
    for {
        // bufsize 1024, read bufsize bytes each time
        res, err := con.Read(b)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
            break
        }
        inBytes = append(inBytes, b[:res]...)
        msg := string(inBytes)
        fmt.Println("receive msg from server:" + msg)
        receive <- msg
    }
}

func getConn() net.Conn {
    con := <-tcpPool
    return con
}

func main() {
    NewClient(20, "localhost:8101")
    con := <-tcpPool
    e := SendMessage(con, []byte("hello, i am client"))
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e.Error())
        return
    }
    go ReceiveMessage(con)
    var msg string
    for {
        select {
        case msg = <-receive:
            fmt.Println(msg)
        }
    }
}
```

server.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
)

func StartTCPServer(network, addr string) error {
    listener, err := net.Listen(network, addr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {

            fmt.Println(err.Error())
            continue

        }
        onConn(conn)
    }
}

//onConn recieves a tcp connection and waiting for incoming messages
func onConn(conn net.Conn) {
    inBytes := make([]byte, 0)
    // load msg
    for {
        buf := make([]byte, 512)
        res, err := conn.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                return
            }
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
            return
        }
        inBytes = append(inBytes, buf[:res]...)

        fmt.Println("receive from client:" + string(inBytes))
        conn.Write([]byte("hello"))
    }
}

func main() {
    if e := StartTCPServer("tcp", ":8101"); e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e.Error())
        return
    }
}
```

this works and no error.
By the way, I can't see where either on the client side or the server side you do con.Close(). It's nessasary to close it.This means a connection once got from the pool, you don't put it back. When you think a connection is over, then close it and build a new connection to fill the pool rather than put it back,beause it's a fatal operation to put a closed con back to the pool.

Comment: thank you for such detailed explaination. I'll try to eliminate all those problems, I think not calling con.Close() is what cause this, like you said, a closed connection has been put  back into the pool and reused in the next  getConn()

Comment: I think I can also move this thread to Stackoverflow codereview forum..